# Can't access RecordTypeId of Account object

Tags: account, record-type, schema

I'm not sure why I can't access the RecordTypeId or any sort of recordtype field of the Account object.

```
//error at select
Account[] accs = [SELECT RecordTypeID, TYPE FROM Account];
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
Set<Id> rIds = R.getRecordTypeInfosById().keySet();
Set<string> rTypes = R.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().keySet();
        
Map<Set<String>, Set<Id>> recTypesMap = new Map<set<string>, set<Id>>();
recTypesMap.put(new set<String>(rTypes), new set<Id>(rIds));
System.debug(accs);
System.debug(recTypesMap); //shows recordtype ids and names, so they do exist
        
String type = '';
for (Account acc : accs){
    if (acc.Type == 'Customer - Direct') {
        type = 'Customer';
    }
    else {
        type = 'Business';
    }
    //error
    //acc.RecordTypeId = '';    
}
```

Comment: Bryar, what error message do you get exactly?

Comment: @FelixvanHove i just tried to run it now, and it works. Im not sure how, i just restarted my laptop!!